# Random in a loop problerm

Tags: random

```
Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

int numberOfFoos = foos.Count;
int fooIndex1 = 0,fooIndex2 = 0;

Foo foo1 = new Foo();
Foo foo2 = new Foo();

do
{
    while(fooIndex1 == fooIndex2)
    {
        fooIndex1 = r.Next(4);
        fooIndex2 = r.Next(4);
    }

    foo1 = foosList[fooIndex1];
    foo2 = foosList[fooIndex2];
}while(foo1.NumberOfLittleFoos == 0 || foo2.NumberOfLittleFoos == 0);
```

Why fooIndex1 is always 0 and fooIndex2 is always 2?  I was trying to use Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode() to generate random integers, but it still doesn't work rightly.

By this code I am trying to select 2 different Foo's from foosList.

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will return same values for `fooIndex1` and `fooIndex2` only if `DateTime.Now.Millisecond` is the same for different runs. It's specified in [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx) class specification. 
I've have run your code twice. First run gives `fooIndex1 = 0, fooIndex2 = 2` and the second `fooIndex1 = 1, fooIndex2 = 3`.

Strange that you use `r.Next(4)`. May be it's better to use `r.Next(foosList.Count)` to be able to access all items in your `foosList`.

Comment: Oh, i had problem in other plac

Comment: I resolved the problem. In foo1. NumberOfLittleFoos and foo2,NumberOfLittleFoos were always 0. Thanks for help!